# D3.js how it's done?

Tags: algorithm, animation, graph, d3.js

I have found [this](http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2012/08/28/us/politics/convention-word-counts.html) somewhere over internet and I'm being curious how it's done that this lib is so smooth (even on my slow PC) and what's more important what algorithm had been used to create that 'sticky' effect. Maybe you know where can I learn about that kind of algorithms?

Thanks for help in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This visualisation uses a [force layout](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout). The algorithm is described in the documentation and you can of course have a look at the source code yourself. You can also have a look at [the source of this particular visualisation](http://graphics8.nytimes.com/newsgraphics/2012/09/04/convention-speeches/c69422ed64123a69dcf8cbdb62c7bd30adaca6d9/index.js) to see what parameters etc were used, but a better way to get started would be to have a look at the documentation and examples on the D3 website.